# Hive query takes forever on Superset

Tags: sql, hive, runtime, apache-superset

I have a query that was written in Presto SQL format (100 lines of insert a query result to a table that already exists) and takes within 10 minutes to get the result.
Now I am going to use Airflow and need to change the query to Hive SQL format to append previous month's data, there is no error, but it is taking 75+ minutes now and the query is still running and not returning any result.
Shall I 'stop' it or is there anything else to consider?

```
SET hive.limit.query.max.table.partition = 1000000;
INSERT INTO TABLE schema.temp_tbl partition(year_month_key)

Select
    distinct
        tbl.account_id,
        tbl.theme_status,
        streaming.streaming_hours,
        tbl.year_month as year_month_key

From
(
Select
    tbl_0.year_month,
    tbl_0.account_id,
    case when max(tbl_0.theme_status) = 1 then 'With Theme' else 'No Theme' end as theme_status

From

(Select
    streaming.year_month,
    streaming.account_id,
    case when theme_events.account_id is not null then 1 else 0 end as theme_status

from
(
Select
    substring(date_key, 1, 7) as year_month,
    last_day(add_months(date_key, -1)) as year_month_ed,
    date_key,
    upper(account_id) as account_id,
    play_seconds

    from agg_device_streaming_metrics_daily

Where date_key between date_add(last_day(add_months(current_date, -2)),1) and last_day(add_months(current_date, -1)) 
  and play_seconds > 0
  
  ) streaming

left join
(
Select
    upper(theme.virtualuserid) as account_id,
    min(theme.createddate) as min_createddate,
    min(theme.date_key) as date_key

From

(
select * from theme_activate_event_history
where date_key between '2019-01-01' and '2020-01-01'
  and activate = 'true' and themetype in ('ThemeBundle','ScreenSaver','Skin','Audio')
 union
select * from theme_activate_event_history
where date_key between '2020-01-01' and '2021-01-01'
  and activate = 'true' and themetype in ('ThemeBundle','ScreenSaver','Skin','Audio')
 union
select * from theme_activate_event_history
where date_key between '2021-01-01' and '2022-01-01'
  and activate = 'true' and themetype in ('ThemeBundle','ScreenSaver','Skin','Audio')
 union
select * from theme_activate_event_history
where date_key between cast('2022-01-01' as date) and last_day(add_months(current_date, -1)) 
  and activate = 'true' and themetype in ('ThemeBundle','ScreenSaver','Skin','Audio')

  ) theme

  group by theme.virtualuserid

    ) theme_events

  on streaming.account_id = theme_events.account_id
 and date(theme_events.date_key) <= date(streaming.year_month_ed)

    ) tbl_0

group by tbl_0.year_month, tbl_0.account_id

    ) tbl

inner join
(Select
    substring(date_key, 1, 7) as year_month,
    upper(account_id) as account_id,
    cast(sum(play_seconds) / 3600 as double) as streaming_hours

    from agg_device_streaming_metrics_daily

Where date_key between date_add(last_day(add_months(current_date, -2)),1) and last_day(add_months(current_date, -1)) 
  and play_seconds > 0
  group by substring(date_key, 1, 7), upper(account_id)
 
  ) streaming

  on tbl.account_id = streaming.account_id and tbl.year_month = streaming.year_month;
```

Comment: Are you using superset or airflow to run your queries? Are you running these in Hive or Presto?

Comment: I am using Superset to run the query (Hive)

Comment: What is the limit selected on superset? Is it too small or large. If it is large try a smaller value.The problem here might be it's taking time to get the results back from hive.

Comment: Yes you might be right and the limit was 1,000 records

Comment: Also you can check the query completion time on Hive side to verify if the returning results is taking time or the query itself taking time to complete.